# How can you edit all permalinks in BlogEngine.NET

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, blogengine.net

I just imported my blog from Wordpress to BlogEngine.NET. Pretty much everything came over correctly. The only missing piece now is figuring out how to change the URLS for all the posts.

I was able to get the date in the URL like I had in WP but that leaves me with 2 problems. There is still the preceding "/post/" as in http://localhost/post/2010/07/11/MyPost.aspx and also the aspx extension.

Is there a way to remove the /post and the requiremenet for the aspx extension? I'd like to be able to maintain my permalink structure that I had on Wordpress.

The structure I have on WP is
http://domain.com/2010/07/10/MyPost/

Comment: i found this BE.net extension but I am getting compilation errors http://www.dexign.net/post/2008/08/05/URL-Rewriting-Extension-For-BlogEngine.aspx when i add it to my site

Comment: Since the blog was moved **from** WordPress I don't think this really applies to WordPress any longer?.. Wrong migration path?

Comment: This was migrated to WordPress Answers from WebApps but WA is clearly not the right place for it. I moved this to StackOverflow because it is a .NET-based solution and SO is the closest site related to .NET I am familiar with. If SO is still wrong, move it along elsewhere....

Answer (score 0):

Removing the aspx extension should be possible on the latest version.

The /post prefix is still hard-coded, you'll have to customize the code to get rid of it.